# How to track camera movement for each frame in a panorama (OpenCV // Android)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, panoramas

After my old development/test tablet ate itself, I'm back to work on my camera app, and am
now working on creating panoramas.  I'd like to be able to direct the user using four
on-screen arrows (move left/right, rotate up/down, and a border around the display showing
red and highlighting the appopriate arrow, then yellow when close, and green when on target
and capture the next image, then move on).

The problem is, I don't know how, using OpenCV or Android capabilities, to determine WHEN
the camera has been rotated the "right" amount.  What is the best way to do this?  Or is
there a best way?  RTFM answers welcome, but please point me to the FM in question.  :-)

Thanks,
   --jim

Comment: Have you made progress with this project? I am looking for a solution to this in the case of ios..

Answer (score 4):

You can give a try to Optical Flow technique. With Optical flow you can quantify how much your camera has moved with respect to the object.Try the following [link](http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf)

Comment: Wow...that's about where I was expecting it might go...except for the massive amount of code required to do it...not to mention re-writing parts of my app to grab frames from the preview OR to do the video side as anything other than an intent.  I hadn't thought about these things, to be honest.  Thanks, though---it should get me off to a good start.  Btw, I haven't seen math like that used in OpenCV docs since college, except in IEEE COMSOC journals (Journal on Selected Areas in Communications) and transactions (Transactions on Antellas and Propagation)....glad I don't have to deal with THAT.

Comment: Basically what you will need if you follow this approach is opencv calcOpticalFlowPyrLK - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html